# align two divs, one at top one at bottom of a third div

Tags: css, html

I have this code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="1"> div 1</div>
    <div id="2"> div 2</div>
</div>
```

I want to put `div 1` at the top, and `div 2` at the bottom of `container`, no matter how much the height of `container` is . How can I do so?

Comment: do you know the heights of either div1 or 2 or are they going to be dynamic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set container's position to relative, and the position of div's 1 and 2 to absolute. Then set div 1 to top:0 and div 2 to bottom 0 (also avoid using number only ID's for CSS compatibility):

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z6BH4/)**

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #999;
}
#div1, #div2 {
    position:absolute;
}
#div1 {
    top:0
}
#div2 {
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! a quick other question, how can I set a div's height equal to the height of my screen, minus another div's height that is on top of it, so say, `<div id="top"></div>` and `<div id="my div">screen height - (top div)height </div>`?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question in your comment. Perhaps you should start a new question about it.

Comment: this only works when there are no other divs below div1 and div2 - otherwise you will experience overflow

Answer (score 10):

Such results can be achieve using `flex properties`. No matter how high the height of the `container`, the two `div`s will always be one at top & another at bottom.

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    flex-direction:column;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

#id{
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Damn what a sexy solution. Thank you men!

Comment: Is there any way to always stick some at the top, another one at the bottom? For example, if you will remove the first div, the second one will place at the top while it should be at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

[Working Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/z6BH4/1/)

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="div1">div 1</div>
   <div id="div2">div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using inline css and most of the times you will need to align the inside divs as well..here is an example (react jsx)

```
 <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent:"flex-end", flexDirection: "column"}}>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 3, display: "flex", justifyContent:"flex-end", flexDirection: "row" }}>{content.sender}</div>
        <div>
            <Bubble type="text">
               <p>{content.text}</p>
            </Bubble>
        </div>
     </div>
```